# PhoneJS back button not working

Tags: phonejs

I created a basic DevExpress PhoneJS v13.2.5 app using the slideout navigation type.  I can switch between views nicely using the slideout menu (URL hash changes).  However, the back button doesn't seem to work.  I expect that when I hit the back button, I would be taken to the previous view based on the URL hash.  However, I am instead taken to the previous page.  So, for example, if my history is as follows:

www.google.com
localhost:4633
localhost:4633/#home
localhost:4633/#foo
localhost:4633/#bar

And I hit the back button (doesn't matter if I'm using Chrome, Android, etc), I would expect to be taken back to localhost:4633/#foo.  However, I am taken back to www.google.com.  Sometimes, before I am taken to the previous page, I briefly see the URL change to localhost:4633/#**root**.

Has this happened to anyone else?  Am I missing something in my app configuration?  From everything I've read in the documentation, it should "just work."  Here is my app init:

```
"use strict";

var MyApp = window.MyApp = {};

$(function () {
    MyApp.app = new DevExpress.framework.html.HtmlApplication({
        namespace: MyApp,

        navigationType: "slideout",
        navigation: [
          {
              title: "Home",
              action: "#home",
              icon: "home"
          },
          {
              title: "Foo",
              action: "#foo",
              icon: "info"
          },
          {
              title: "Bar",
              action: "#bar",
              icon: "info"
          }
        ]
    });

    MyApp.app.router.register(":view", { view: "home" });
    MyApp.app.navigate();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Back button is available in each view in a stack except for the **root** view. If you create a link with `MyApp.app.navigate('Foo')` in your Home view, click on that link and go to the "Foo" page, then you can back in the Home page by pressing back button. Please see:
 [Navigation History](http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Howto/Navigation_and_Routing#Navigation_History) For further detailed informations.